# Excel form submitting to incorrect location

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a number of forms, how they work in a very basic fashion is form 1 inputs a set of data with an accompanying reference number, a user then inputs that reference number into form 2.

This tells Excel which entry to append the data from form 2 to, so for example if on the sheet there is reference numbers 01, 02 and 03. A user inputs 03 into form 2, this tells Excel to append any data in form 2 to entry 03.

What I currently have is form 2 can append 1 work order number per reference, what I want to do is have the ability to have a listbox with upto 20 work order numbers that can all be appended to a single reference.

The problem I am having is no matter what reference number is input on form 2, the list data is submitted to the second row.

Below is the code I have for the entirety of form 2

```
    Private Sub Production_Submit_Click()

'Locks all fields within the form and also displays a msgbox informing the user of this if trying to submit information to the sheet within inputting a Sales Order Number
If SalesOrderProd = "" Then
WorkOrderNo.Locked = True
ProdDesc.Locked = True
ProdDate.Locked = True
ProdComplete.Locked = True
MsgBox "Please insert a Sales Order Number to continue", vbCritical, "Missing Sales Order Number"
Exit Sub

Else
WorkOrderNo.Locked = False
ProdDesc.Locked = False
ProdDate.Locked = False
ProdComplete.Locked = False
End If

Dim Reference As String
Dim wkord As String

Reference = Trim(SalesOrderProd.Text)
LastRow = Worksheets("Sales Order Log").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow

'Submits the Production information to the sheet
If Worksheets("Sales Order Log").Cells(i, 2).Value = Reference Then
'Worksheets("Sales Order Log").Cells(i, 10).Value = WorkOrderNo
Worksheets("Sales Order Log").Cells(i, 11).Value = ProdDesc
Worksheets("Sales Order Log").Cells(i, 12).Value = ProdDate
Worksheets("Sales Order Log").Cells(i, 13).Value = ProdComplete

For j = LBound(Me.WkOrderList.list) To UBound(Me.WkOrderList.list)
    wkord = wkord & IIf(wkord = "", "", vbNewLine) & Me.WkOrderList.list(j, 0)
Next

With Sheets("Sales Order Log").Range("Sales_Data_Start")
    .Offset(TargetRow, 1).Value = SalesOrderNo
    ' (...)
    
    .Offset(j, 9).Value = wkord
End With

End If

Next

'Displays a message box informing the user that the form information has been input into the spreadsheet
MsgBox "Information added to Sales Order: " & SalesOrderProd & " successfully", vbInformation, "Production"

'Blanks the form once information has been submitted to the sheet
SalesOrderProd.Value = ""
WorkOrderNo.Value = ""
ProdDesc.Value = ""
ProdDate.Value = ""
ProdComplete.Value = ""
WkOrderList.Clear

End Sub
```

The below code is the snippet being used to submit the data to the sheet from the form

```
    'Submits the Production information to the sheet
If Worksheets("Sales Order Log").Cells(i, 2).Value = Reference Then
'Worksheets("Sales Order Log").Cells(i, 10).Value = WorkOrderNo
Worksheets("Sales Order Log").Cells(i, 11).Value = ProdDesc
Worksheets("Sales Order Log").Cells(i, 12).Value = ProdDate
Worksheets("Sales Order Log").Cells(i, 13).Value = ProdComplete

For j = LBound(Me.WkOrderList.list) To UBound(Me.WkOrderList.list)
    wkord = wkord & IIf(wkord = "", "", vbNewLine) & Me.WkOrderList.list(j, 0)
Next

With Sheets("Sales Order Log").Range("Sales_Data_Start")
    .Offset(TargetRow, 1).Value = SalesOrderNo
    ' (...)
    
    .Offset(j, 9).Value = wkord
End With

End If
```

Thank you for any help on this and I am sorry for the convoluted explanation.

Comment: So if the user enters (eg) "03" as a reference number, it will always match line 2, even if the reference number on that line is not "03" ?  `If Worksheets("Sales Order Log").Cells(i, 2).Value = Reference Then` seems correct, so it's difficult for us to know why that's not working as expected.

Comment: Yes exactly, the work order list seems to ignore what reference number the user loaded and just loads the list into reference 02

Comment: So which specific line are we talking about ?  Which line is writing to the wrong place?  You use `i` and `TargetRow` but its unclear where that second variable comes from.

Comment: The second snippet of code

Comment: If  it's the first few lines of that code then it looks fine to me.

Comment: What specifically is "the list data"?  If you mean `wkord` then there's nothing in your code which directs that to the matched line...

Comment: The list box is handled within the for loop, the rest of the form is handled within the if statement

Comment: What *specifically* is getting written to the wrong place?  All of the form data?

Comment: Thank you for your replies Tim, your comment about wkord not being linked to a matched line struck a chord in my head and it turns out the code was just in the wrong place, it needed to sit inside the if statement. Thank you for your comments today